# Customize IntelliJ Material Theme pull and push icons

Tags: intellij-idea, material-design, phpstorm, webstorm

The material theme for IntelliJ/WebStorm/PhpStorm/etc... is great and I love it but I just have one thing I can't stand: the choice of push and pull icons.

I found that it's possible to customize a great number of things in the Material Theme or IntelliJ in general in the settings menu.

If I want to set these two icons (alone) (I like the rest of the Material icons) to the default IntelliJ push and pull icons would it be possible and how?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the **IntelliJ Platform SDK DevGuide** > "*Customizing UI Themes*": https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/reference_guide/ui_themes/themes_customize.html#customizing-icons

Comment: Sorry, can't advise further. You can try asking this at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979-IntelliJ-IDEA-Open-API-and-Plugin-Development or at https://github.com/ChrisRM/material-theme-jetbrains/issues